# Writing to sdcards options

Tags: android, usb, android-sdcard

I have a simple app that writes data to a sdcard. Implementing the getExternalStoragePublicDirectory() method. Under my storage folder, there are 3 options, sdcard0 sdcard1 and usb(have an external usb storage connected) that the phone sees as an sdcard. Calling the above method writes to sdcard0. My question is, is there anyway I can make it write to either of the other two folders?

Comment: `Under my storage folder, there are 3 options` ? What is your 'storage folder'?

Comment: Hi, I have a storage folder(same directory level as acct,etc,mnt) showing in my file explorer. It contains three folders...sdcard0, sdcard1 and usb

Comment: Why are you calling that 'options'? So there is a /storage folder in the file system and there are sub folders /storage/sdcard0, /storage/sdcard1 and /storage/usb. You know the paths because you used a file explorer. Your app will not know them. So what is the question exactly?

Comment: thanks, my question is, the native method getExternalStoragePublicDirectory() writes to /storage/sdcard0..is there a way to make it write to /storage/usb?

Comment: or how would I go about it?

Comment: That native method does not write. It just gives you a path. And not`/storage/sdcard0` but `/storage/sdcard0/DCIM/Pictures` for instance. You have other code that will write.  Please rephrase.

Comment: Thanks, what method would I use to get the path I want to write to?

Comment: Basically when I mount the usb storage, I want to grab the path to the usb storage.

Comment: If you can mount then you know the path already i would think.